# Objective C C++ if(cin >> variable) equivilant

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I would like to have an `if` statement in objective C that says if the user properly enters the variable, do this. So for example if the variable is an integer and the user enters too many digits(over the max amount in an integer) the program does something to not accept that. In C++ the equivalent is

```
while (true)
{   
   if (cin >> intvariable)
   {    
     break;
   }
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: write your code as Objective-C++. Then you can use whatever C++ iostreams code you like best.